# Track the view using code like google developer tools?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, reactjs

I am a new web developer and just started working. i am doing debugging and fixing errors now. so the website is so huge and i have access to the whole code. if i get an issue saying fix heading "my heading" to "my own heading", its easy to locate where the code is by doing a search on the code editor like visual code, but how do i know where exactly is that "my heading" is on the website. i tried development tool, it is limited due to alot of code is traspiled so code on editor and development tool is not the same. is there a solution ? it is killing alot of time, asking co workers all the time seems not right either .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to fix errors of html you can use this web site: https://validator.w3.org/

Have you try to use "Console" direct from the browser? if you use chrome, you can run the code inspector by doing right click on the webpage and there you can search for specific line of code, tag, and so on, or modify right there on the inspector the java code and run it to see if its working properly.

Hope it helps, regards.